# Array unset not working in all circumstances

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large multi-dimensional array of vehicles that I am trying to filter through based on family and model selections.

When a user selects a family, it searches through the array and removes all vehicles not in that family. It works.

When a user selects a model, it searches through the array and removes all vehicles not in that family. It works.

However when both family and model filters are selected, the family filter works but the model filter fails to unset.

```
if( $family != 'All' ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $details as &$d ) {
        $s = recursive_array_search( $family, $d, 5 ); // 5 is family column
        if($s == false) { 
            unset($details[$i]); 
            $c--;
        }
        $i++; 
    }
}       

if( $model != 'All' ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach( $details as &$d ) {
        $s = recursive_array_search( $model, $d, 6 ); // 6 is trim/model column
        if($s == false) { 
            unset($details[$i]); 
            $c--;
        }
        $i++; 
    }
}
```

Interestingly, $c, my global counter to track what is left over in the array after all the filtering, works always, even when the unset is failing.

Comment: Please edit the tags to include the appropriate language.

Comment: I have a feeling that what is presented isn't a continuous section of code... maybe functions where you're doing some pass by reference which the [unset documentation](http://us3.php.net/unset) contains some caveats in regards.  However, why set all those values and then unset them later?  Why not refuse to add them when the array is populated?

Comment: @JeremyMiller Refusing to populate initially would be better code for sure. Not sure why it wasn't done like that initially.  However, these two blocks of code actually are right after each other.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Good news. I reversed the code and refused to populate based on the filters. For whatever reason, it appears to work now. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it's working as desired!